# Is it possible to copy a folder of files to the application directory from a dependent project in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

In my solution, I have **Project A** (an application) and **Project B** (a class library to encapsulate API functionality). **B** is a reference of **A**.

---

Project A (application)

- Dependency 1
- Dependency 2
- Project B

  - /api/files

Project C (application)

- Dependency 1
- Project B

  - /api/files

---

The API for Project B requires a few dozen files in a specific folder structure to be present on the machine. I created a post-build event to *xcopy* the folder from the project to the target directory - **Project.B/bin/Release** - which works fine when building that project.

When I build A, I would like the files to copy to **Project.A/bin/Release** so I deploy the contents of that bin folder. Currently, building **A** just refreshes the files in **Project.B/bin/Release**

My current best guess is to move the files to a location that is shared across the entire solution and make an *xcopy* build event for every application (there are a few Project A's) but I don't like this because it decouples the files from the project and I need to add the build event whenever I include the dependency. However, I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question I think you may want to look at the **Reserved and Well-Known MSBuild Properties** here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx

Specifically I'm referring to things like **MSBuildThisFileDirectory**, **MSBuildProjectDirectory** and such.

Using these you could create a dynamic property which determines the output/copy path of your API files. So if you are just building Project B, the files would go to **Project.B/bin/Release**. But when you build Project A, the files would go to **Project.A/bin/Release**

Not knowing your exact setup, here's a very basic and general example:

**Project A:**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ApiCopyPath Condition="'$(ApiCopyPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\Release</ApiCopyPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="ProjectA">
    ...
    <MSBuild Projects="ProjectB" Properties="ApiCopyPath=$(ApiCopyPath)" />
</Target>
```

**Project B:**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ApiCopyPath Condition="'$(ApiCopyPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\Release</ApiCopyPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="ProjectB">
    ...
    <XCopy Target="$(TargetPath)" Destination="$(ApiCopyPath)" />
</Target>
```

So each "Project A" would get its own copy of your "Project B" binaries. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Quick Question - When I am building Project A, is there any way to access the target path of project A through the MSBuild file of Project B? Ideally I would only have one MSBuild file that always puts the api files in the application bin directory.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to access "parent" project info from a child project. See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a718f5e-65bf-4b91-b78e-feae14b4ad95/accessing-parent-project-from-invoked-child-project?forum=msbuild

However, you could still create an "intermediate" MSBuild file to do all the "work" and then the only thing you would need from each of your "Project A" files is the directory path, which you can pass down through the Properties.

Comment: Thanks again. I am marking this answer correct because the combination of your answer and the discussion in the link from your comment is really what I needed to help me understand.